# Bash workaround, printing environment variable in comment

Tags: bash, makefile

I am using a makefile to run a pipeline, the number of cores is set in the makefile as an environment variable.

At one point in the pipeline the makefile will execute a wrapper script which will start an LSF job array (HPC).

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -J hybrid_job_name      # job name
#BSUB -n 32                   # number of cores in job
#BSUB -o output.%J.hybrid     # output file name

mpirun.lsf ./program_name.exe
```

The only problem here is that in the wrapper script the -n flag shoud be set by the 'CORES' environment variable, and not hard coded to 32. Is there anyway to work around so I can pass the CORES environment variable to the -n flag.

Comment: Could you provide the line of code where this wrapper script is called?  There probably is an easy way to achieve what you want to do, but it will require changing the way you are calling this wrapper script.

Comment: This is not a `bash` question; it's a question about whatever program interprets those comments.

Comment: Whence the comments starting `#BSUB`? Don't you want to pass these arguments to `./program_name.exe` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate the wrapper script that contains the "#BSUB" directives on the fly, before submitting it to LSF. E.g. create a template such as `job_script.tmpl` in advance:

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -J hybrid_job_name      # job name
#BSUB -n %CORES%              # number of cores in job
#BSUB -o output.%J.hybrid     # output file name

mpirun.lsf ./program_name.exe
```

and then in your makefile do:

```
sed s/%CORES%/${CORES}/g job_script.tmpl > job_script.lsf
bsub < job_script.lsf
```

Alternatively, you can set options to `bsub` on the command line as well as via `#BSUB` directives inside the job script. So in the makefile do:

```
bsub -n $CORES < job_script.lsf
```

The value passed to `bsub` on the command line will override the value defined by the `#BSUB -n` directive inside the job script. This way is a bit simpler but the first way has the benefit of recording the number of cores used in the job, for future reference.